# Add programmatically exposed filter to view without removing the existing ones

Tags: 7, views

I want to add an exposed filter to a view which contains already exposed filters but without altering them.
When I add the following code it messes up  the exposed filters from the view and only the programmatically coded exposed filter works correctly.

I use the following code:

```
function music_m_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id = null , &$args = null) 
{
$filter = $view->display['default']->handler->options['filters'];       
$current_latter = arg(1);      
$filter['field_last_name_value']['value'] = $current_latter;

$view->display_handler->override_option('filters', $filter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook function used was wrong. I had to use hook_views_pre_build(&$view)
so I have now the following (and the other exposed filters don't get messed up):

```
 function music_m_views_pre_build(&$view) {

$view_filters = $view->display['default']->handler->options['filters']; 

 $current_latter = arg(1); 

 if($current_latter)
 {  
    $view_filters['title']['value'] = $current_latter;  

 } 
$view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->handlers['filter']['title']->value = $current_latter;
```

}